# Simple checkup for existing values in db not working

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I have a database called `casino` where I have a table called `cards`, in which there are `card_numbers` and `points`. This is an example of the database entry.

```
+------------------------+
|         cards          |
+------------------------+
| card_number  |  points |
+------------------------+
|    55555     |   200   |
+------------------------+
```

I parse .csv files and update the points of each card number. If I have more entries of the same card number in one .csv, I keep the first one and skip everything else regarding that card number. When I hit a card number that already exists in the database, I just UPDATE the `points` value by the former value and the new value. This is my implementation, but something is not working.

Can you please try to help me to see what's wrong?

```
// function to check if the user already exists in the database
function exists_in_database($db_handle, $card_number)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT * FROM `cards` WHERE card_number='".$card_number."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
        return true;
    else
    {
        return false;
        if (!mysqli_query($db_handle,$query))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// function to update points of a specific card number
function update_points_in_database($db_handle, $card_number, $points)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($db_handle, "UPDATE `cards` SET `points` = `points` + ".$points." WHERE `card_number` = ".$card_number."");
}

/* DATABASE PART */
$servername = "localhost"; // database host
$username = "root"; // database user
$password = "root"; // database password
$db_name = "casino"; // database name

// create connection
$db_handle = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// check connection
if($db_handle->connect_error)
    die("Connection <b>failed</b>: " . $db_handle->connect_error . "<br />");


/* PARSING PART */
for($key = 0; $key < count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']); $key++)
{
    $tmp_file_path = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

    if($tmp_file_path)
    {
        $new_file_path = 'uploaded-' . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_path, $new_file_path))
        {
            // opening
            if(!($handle = fopen($new_file_path, "r")))
                die("fopen failed. reason: " . $error_get_last());

            // helper count var
            $count = 0;
            // array of card numbers we already read
            $cards_passed = [];
            while(!feof($handle)) // until we're done with one .csv
            {
                // add to helper var
                $count++;
                // parse the file
                $contents = fgetcsv($handle, NULL, ";");

                // skip the header (umisteni, body...)
                if($count < 2)
                    continue;
                // if there is nothing there
                else if($contents[0] == NULL)
                    continue;
                // if there is anything else than a number in the card number
                else if(!is_numeric($contents[0]))
                    continue;

                $card_number = $contents[0]; // card number
                $points = $contents[5]; // points
                if($contents[6]) // if we have extra points
                    $points += $contents[6]; // add them to the total

                if(exists_in_database($card_number)) // check if we already have this card in database
                {
                    if(in_array($card_number, $cards_passed)) // more occurences in one files, skip that
                        continue;

                    // first occurence
                    update_points_in_database($db_handle, $card_number, $points); // update the points in db
                    array_push($cards_passed, $card_number); // so we know we already passed this card number
                    echo "The card number " . $card_number . " has been updated with " . $points . " points.<br />";
                    continue;
                }

                // otherwise we simply insert the card number
                $sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points)
                        VALUES ('$card_number', $points)";
                array_push($cards_passed, $card_number);

                // if everything went smoothly
                if($db_handle->query($sql) === TRUE)
                    if($contents[6]) // extra points
                        echo "The card number " . $card_number . " has been added with " . $points . " (including extra " . $contents[6] . " points).<br />";
                    else // no extra points
                        echo "The card number " . $card_number . " has been added with " . $points . " points.<br />";
                // if we got an error
                else
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . $db_handle->error; // let us know
            }
            echo "<br /><br />"; // new file


            // closing
            if(!(fclose($handle)))
                // if we have an error while closing
                echo "fclose failed. reason: " . $error_get_last();
        }
        // error possibility
        else
            // let us know
            die("Error while handling the files!");
    }   
}
$db_handle->close();
```

When the system hits the same card number in a different file, it throws the following error:

> Error: INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points) VALUES ('12165', 443)
>   Duplicate entry '12165' for key 'card_number'Error: INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points) VALUES ('12180', 133)

But I have no idea why it does that, because I think I treated that with the conditional statements.

EDIT:

I'm using

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points) VALUES ('$card_number', $points) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `cards` SET `points` = `points` + ".$points."";
```

but that gives me a syntax error. Any ideas why please?

Comment: First error means, You already have a card_number 12165 in the database, and it will not let the same thing a second time to write

Comment: @frantsium But the script checks whether the card is already there -- that's the point of the question.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option in `INSERT`, instead of doing multiple queries?

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points) VALUES ('$card_number', $points) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`cards\` SET \`points\` = \`points\` + ".$points."";` this gives me a syntax error, why is that?

Comment: any help please? still didn't figure it out...

Comment: @user3647430, I'm guessing the `card_number` column is the primary key which means you cannot assign the same value to another record.  Try changing the database so that `card_number` is not the primary(or unique?) key.  Also, I'm not sure if I remember correct, but shouldn't $points have some `'` around it?  Might be wrong about that part :P  Maybe create an `id` column and assign it as the primary key and have it auto-increment.  That way you have a primary key and you can insert as many duplicate `card_number`'s as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own, this is what I needed:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cards (card_number, points) VALUES ('$card_number', $points) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `points` = `points` + $points";
```